# Differential calculus question - Not sure how to approach this question

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Let $f$ be the function defined by $$f(x) = x^n(x + 3)$$ where $n$ is an integer greater than or equal to $2$.
>  (a) Find all critical points of $f$.
>  (b) Find the intervals on which $f$ is increasing or decreasing.
>  (c) Use the information from the previous two parts to determine whether the critical points are local maxima, local minima, or neither.  (Do not use any information about the second derivative, just the sign of the first derivative.)

I do not know how to approach this question. I found the first derivative which is $f^{'}(x)=3nx^{n-1} + nx^n + x^n$. According to this i tried to find the critical points and got: $x=0, -\frac{3n}{n+1}$.

I'm not sure if this is correct and how to find the interval that it is increasing and decreasing. What confuses me is how to work around the $n$. Any guidance or help would be much appreciated thank you! The question is the image below.

Comment: Please don't rely on pictures of text.

Comment: What you did is correct. Those critical points split the real line into three intervals. In each interval, pick a "test point" (e.g., on $(-3n/(n+1),0)$, you can pick $-1$) and evaluate the derivative there. The sign will tell you whether $f$ is increasing or decreasing over the interval.

Comment: @Shaun My apologies, this is the first time I am posting on here. Will make sure not to use pictures next time, thanks :)

Comment: @DavidMitra Thank you for your help! I will try doing that.